# VHDL Overmapping and Time Constaint issues in Xilinx-ISE

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, ise, modelsim

I have an issue with a module I use for rotation of a vector. I have two operations one uses 2 rotLeft modules and the other uses 2 rotRights. Originally I had occupied Slices overmapping issues which led me to combine the modules which helped a lot however now I am having issues with timing constraints in Xilinx, which results in incorrect output when programmed to an FPGA dev board. I've realized the issue is the rotation modules, when commenting out the four rotation modules port map the designs max speed is around 111Mhz and when in use 1.66Mhz, when only 2 are used it is around 44Mhz max which is fine since operating is 25Mhz. Their are 4 rotation modules in use; however, only 2 are needed at a time, depending on if a button is pressed on the board or not. I attempted to turn two off at a time by switching the with/select clause with a process gaurd and a case statement; however, I end up with LUT Overmapped issues (158%, usually 71%).

Does anyone have any advice for dealing with timing constraints and overmapping issues in Xilinx, or a way to improve the below module?

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY rotLeft IS
    PORT (
    din     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);  -- Input to be rotated
    amnt    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);   --Amount to Rotate by
    dout    : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0) -- Rotated Input
     );
END rotLeft;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF rotLeft IS
    SIGNAL rot  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    WITH amnt SELECT -- din <<< amnt
        rot<= 
            din(30 DOWNTO 0) & din(31)           WHEN "00001", --01
            din(29 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 30) WHEN "00010", --02
            din(28 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 29) WHEN "00011", --03
            din(27 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 28) WHEN "00100", --04
            din(26 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 27) WHEN "00101", --05
            din(25 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 26) WHEN "00110", --06
            din(24 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 25) WHEN "00111", --07
            din(23 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 24) WHEN "01000", --08
            din(22 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 23) WHEN "01001", --09
            din(21 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 22) WHEN "01010", --10
            din(20 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 21) WHEN "01011", --11
            din(19 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 20) WHEN "01100", --12
            din(18 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 19) WHEN "01101", --13
            din(17 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 18) WHEN "01110", --14
            din(16 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 17) WHEN "01111", --15
            din(15 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 16) WHEN "10000", --16
            din(14 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 15) WHEN "10001", --17
            din(13 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 14) WHEN "10010", --18
            din(12 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 13) WHEN "10011", --19
            din(11 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 12) WHEN "10100", --20
            din(10 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 11) WHEN "10101", --21
            din(09 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 10) WHEN "10110", --22
            din(08 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 09) WHEN "10111", --23
            din(07 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 08) WHEN "11000", --24
            din(06 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 07) WHEN "11001", --25
            din(05 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 06) WHEN "11010", --26
            din(04 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 05) WHEN "11011", --27
            din(03 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 04) WHEN "11100", --28
            din(02 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 03) WHEN "11101", --29  
            din(01 DOWNTO 0) & din(31 DOWNTO 02) WHEN "11110", --30
            din(0)           & din(31 DOWNTO 01) WHEN "11111", --31
            din                                  WHEN OTHERS;

        dout <= rot;
END rtl;
```

EDIT:
This is the code for the encryption/decryption https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd91224afa3192cd2cf2

Comment: What fpga generation are you using? What is your critical path from the timing report? That rotation should be fine by itself if you pipeline properly.

Comment: Spartan 3E, 415ns after using SmartExplorer, It is for an encryption type module, and I implemented both encryption and decryption on the same board.

Comment: Can you give the critical **path**, not just its length.

Comment: I actually thought that was the critical path. I was unsure so i generated a Post Place & Route Timing Analysis https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1b5bcb6aa3b06251d66d

Comment: Also if it helps the design is to be implemented on a Basys2 board

Comment: This is the code for the encryption/decryption https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd91224afa3192cd2cf2

Answer (score 3):

From the timing report you attached, the critical path has **378** levels of logic in it. I can't emphasize enough how much 378 levels is, from the project I'm working on (video compression), my critical path is only 8 levels deep.

This is part of your problem, not only the propagation delays are enormous from going trough so many LUTs, ISE has a lot of problem routing the design in an efficient way. You need to add registers to pipeline your design, it is much easier to route a pipelined design and you will get faster speed and smaller area. Beside, registers are virtually free in FPGAs.

For instance, your *rotLeft* entity should have registered inputs and outputs, and it will then easily run at 100MHz, even in a spartan-3E. In my design, I always register my output, and assumes the inputs are registered (since they come from the output of another module).

Another part of your problem is these combinational loops that ISE report. Those are likely to change or even disappear once you redesign to add pipeline registers, but you shouldn't even try a bitstream with these in it.

Comment: So it is more beneficial to use process guards and additional buffer signals for each signal in I/O?

This is the code for the encryption/decryption gist.github.com/anonymous/cd91224afa3192cd2cf2

Comment: Yes, the complexity for the design tool is exponential with logic depth (I don't know the actual relationship, but you get the idea). It is much better to divide a 95 ns operation into 10 10ns operations. Looking at your code, there is no reason why most signals wouldn't be registered, it will change the control logic though.

Comment: Is it better to break up the with/select statements which repurpose the register depending on if the module is in encryption or decryption mode such as "WITH enc SELECT 
  a_round <= din(63 DOWNTO 32) + skey(0) WHEN '0',--A = A + S[0]
     a_reg - skey(0) WHEN OTHERS; --A = A - S[0]" Into say 3 separate statement one for the encryption=addition, the other for decryption=subtraction and the third a with select statement ie "WITH enc SELECT 
  a_round <= enc_data WHEN '0',--A = A + S[0]
     dec_data WHEN OTHERS; --A = A - S[0]"other than that from my limited experience think everything register

Comment: In this case, you have a 32-bits mux (`din/a_reg`) followed by an adder-subtractor (`s[0]`). I definitely expect a 32 bits adder-subtractor to be registered. If I'm looking for high performances, I would also register the result of the mux.

Answer (score 2):

The right/left rotate operator is simply a mux tree, so the real reasons for this could be unrelated to the ror/rol:

- you may be connecting the modules in a wrong or partially recursive way, with not enough registers to cut combinational paths. If you are using a modern FPGA, there's no way such a mux tree could hinder frequency so much if it is properly connected to the rest of the design.
- you may have no registers at all in the design, not even for inputs and outputs. This could easily result in very slow paths.
- your device may be too full, making it very hard for placement & routing to converge to a good solution.

It may also be none of the things I suggested. You should definitely check warnings in synthesis and P&R and perhaps also check that the synthesized netlist is the same as what you would expect.

Comment: Their are a few warnings that mostly with my use of conv_integer and another dealing with missing signals from process sensitivity lists. However; the only one that I am unsure of is "Xst:2170 - Unit rc5 : the following signal(s) form a combinatorial loop:" their are around 32 of them and it appears right before the warning about not meeting timing constraints.

Comment: That's your problem then. A combinational loop is a circuit with feedback with no registers or latches to cut the feedback path. Did you simulate the design? You should be able to see a combinational loop as it almost surely breaks simulation too.

Comment: In any case, also fix the sensitivity lists. You might be synthesizing unwanted latches instead of combinational logic (this is unrelated with your current problem though)

Comment: yes I did a functional and timing simulation in modelsim and the design resulted in the correct values, which is why I ignored it initially.

Comment: Missing signals from sensitivity list is the main reason why implementation doesn't match simulation. Fix your sensitivity lists and simulate again.

Comment: I suggest you carefully check the way you connected those modules and/or investigate the combinational loop path in ISE. The LUTs in an FPGA are not meant to be used in feedback loops and that's the reason for your huge timing problems.

Comment: I fixed the sensitivity list issue, which was odd since some signals weren't even being used inside the process their were only 3. Their are warnings for index values not matching array range but i suppose thats because of conv_integer and signals being trimmed but i don't think that is a huge issue. The issues with Combinatorial loop is odd as it doesn't give more information

Comment: Mapping now gives an additional warning before the issues with the time constraints  

"Pack:266 - The function generator Sh22319 failed to merge with F5 multiplexer Sh22231_f5.  There is a conflict for the FXMUX.  The design will exhibit suboptimal timing."

Comment: Until you break the combinational loop the synthesis will struggle to map your design, which is probably what happens here. How did you connect these ror/rol modules? The loop is certainly not inside them, so it should be in their instantiation if you say that removing them solves the issue.

Comment: @JonathanDrolet I cannot comment on your answer unfortunately :( I cannot see the timing report from my phone, but you are right: the sheer number of logic levels is another sign of something terribly wrong (combinational loop, no registers in the design, HDL used in a software-ish fashion - that is not RTL - or a combination of all these)

Comment: I tried updating the ror/rol modules by creating 3 signals analogous to din,amnt and dout and feeding them the respective input inside a process gaurd with clk in the synthesis list. This actually increased the critical path to around 9ns; however, it produces the incorrect output.

Comment: 1) of course, your "correct" results need a feedback path so if you simply cut it with flops it will be synthesizable but produce wrong results. Your logic is simply faulty and you should change that not inside the ror/rol modules but on the upper level of hierarchy, I.e where you instantiate them. 2) 9ns is no increase of the critical path with respect to the version where you had no ror/rol modules. Tclk=9ns means fclk=111 MHz. This is yet another proof that that combinational loop is responsible for your poor timing. But again, you must solve this by removing it - it is logically wrong.

Comment: My apologies I meant the critical path decreased though that was only on initial change

Comment: Ok. But what I wrote still stands :) it could be useful if you shared the RTL code where you instantiate your modules.

Comment: I actually added a link to a gist with the RTL code in the comments section and also edited the thread at the bottom 

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd91224afa3192cd2cf2

Comment: Ok so two things: 1) before you inserted a_reg, b_reg there were clear combinational loops, e.g. ab_xor depended on a,b, a_rotated_left depended on ab_xor and a depended on a_rotated_loop. You cut the loop with the registers, but you also have to change your control to make sure this works. 2) you added registers using the wrong syntax!!! A synchronous flip flop with asynchronous reset must only have clk and reset signals on the process sensitivity list. If you also put din, you are synthesizing a latch.

Comment: In general: combinational logic = process with ALL inputs (explicit or not) in the sensitivity list; sequential synchronous logic = process wit ONLY clocks and asynchronous resets on the sensitivity list. This is EXTREMELY important. All processes not following these rules will likely be simulated as combinational or sequential synchronous logic, but may be synthesized as unwanted latches.

Comment: I don't think this is correct but I added intermediate signals and 2 large processes to handle the signal combinations and the mux https://gist.github.com/anonymous/98bf142500ff590b565c. I now recieve some 32 warnings from XISE about "Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <b_round_enc_31> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <rc5>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process."
Of course the output is incorrect but the critical path is now an acceptable 16ns.

Comment: A suggestion coming from experience: don't even bother synthesizing until you get a correct behavior in simulation. In any case, the warnings indicate that b_round_enc is never used / is always 0. This indicates a probable logic error (but you already know this, if this doesn't work in simulation).

Comment: haha I see, I can't seem to get the values right at all, once I put all of the logic into registers. Since those particular signals are part of a loop before counting up I created an additional signal that counted from 1-n and delays the primary counter by n. I figured n would be the number of stages until the data propagated the correct answer but I seem to be missing something. I gave the code minus the counter in the previous comment.

Comment: One thing I can see in a quick look at your RTL is that there's some confusion in the way you are scheduling your operations in time. For example, you still "update" `a` using at least in one case `a_rot_left`, a value that is computed combinationally using `a`. You must clearly rethink the way you implement the algorithm commented above. One suggestion is that RTL design is nothing like coding high level software: you *must* have a clear idea of the structure of your RTL even if you code it behaviorally, to avoid loops such as the one I see here.

Comment: Try to draw a simple scheme on a piece of paper where your blocks are clearly defined, including the timing relationships. Separate distinct discrete instants using registers. There are many ways to do this: for example you could take the algorithm above (in the comment in your code) and decide that every assignment happens in a distinct instant, hence adding a register after every assignment and driving the algorithmic for loop with a counter. Or, you could add some concurrency and decide that some of those assignments can happen concurrently.